# rpm maven plugin not creating directory

Tags: maven

I am creating the rpm of my project, and trying to copy some resource files to a particular directory, but directory itself is not getting created. Here is my code. I wanted directory resources to be created in my project root directory.

```
<mapping>
    <directory>/${rpm-root}/${comp-name}/${install-path}/resources</directory>
    <filemode>775</filemode>
    <configuration>false</configuration>
    <directoryIncluded>true</directoryIncluded>
    <recurseDirectories>true</recurseDirectories>
    <sources>
        <source>
            <location>src/main/resources</location>
            <excludes>
                <exclude>**/*.pyc</exclude>
                <exclude>**/version.txt</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.gitignore</exclude>
                <exclude>**/ETF.xml</exclude>
                <exclude>**/*.sql</exclude>
            </excludes>
        </source>
    </sources>
</mapping>
```

Any help please?

Comment: Do I need to create the directory or <directory> here will do the job for me.

Comment: As per [the docs](http://www.mojohaus.org/rpm-maven-plugin/map-params.html#directory) `<directory>` dictates where the file included in that mapping will be installed. You say you want them installed in your _root directory_, but your configuration implies otherwise `/${rpm-root}/${comp-name}/${install-path}/resources`. I do not know what values those variables have and whether their concatenated results represent the root of your app, but at least `resources` sounds like a sub-folder to me...

Comment: yes resources is a subfolder, which does not exist but I want this to be created here. These variables evaluate to value like /opt/project/root. In nutshell I want 'resources' directory to be created inside /opt/project/root. Packaging should be done like files from src/main/resources to be copied to /opt/project/root/resources.

Comment: Then that should be it, perhaps except the initial `/` if `${rpm-root}` already has one at the beginning.

Comment: somehow this is not working. And as per the doc <directory> value must start with /.

Comment: Then check the maven and rpm installation logs for errors. Also if you're using windows you can use 7zip to open the resulting rpm (and internal cpio) to see the contents. Regarding the `/`, I was thinking that maybe `${rpm-root}=/opt` so the concatenation would result in `//opt`.